# WPF - How to know if browser loaded the webpage with/without error?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

WPF Application - I want to know whether loading of web page was successful or failed. Means, I should be able to know if the browser is having the error like "This page can’t be displayed". I am hosting a form of web browser control within my application. Please help.

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK you can't (unless you workaround attaching to both `Navigating` and `Loaded` and assume it failed after a timeout). `NavigateError` event exposed by the COM object isn't attached to anything in internal `WebBrowserEvent` class then, unless you rewrite some of their code to attach a sink and use Reflection to read `HostingAdaptor` property,  you're out of luck.

Comment: Is it enough for you if you detect a navigation error?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Yes, you are right, I tried a lot with few tricks, but problem didn't solved.
I tried to read the error text in the browser document, also tried to create new request and response in documentcompleted, but both the ways are not ideal. Anyways, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @RezaAghaei - NavigateError event isn't attached in internal WebBrowserEvent. So I am unable to find it.

Comment: You can find it, check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw)`. Then you can get activeX browser control from wpf web browser control and subscribe to its [`NavigateError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

The event will raise when an error occurs during navigation.

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var axBrowser = this.wpfWebBrowser1.GetType().InvokeMember("ActiveXInstance",
        BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null, wpfWebBrowser1, new object[] { }) as SHDocVw.WebBrowser;
    axBrowser.NavigateError += axBrowser_NavigateError;
    this.wpfWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com/xxxxxxx"); //status: 404
    //this.wpfWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://elgoog.com"); //status: -2146697211
}

void axBrowser_NavigateError(object pDisp, ref object URL, ref object Frame, 
                             ref object StatusCode, ref bool Cancel)
{
    MessageBox.Show(StatusCode.ToString());
}
```

In above code I supposed you have a web browser control with name `wpfWebBrowser1`.
Don't forget to add `using System.Reflection;`.
Don't forget to assign `MainWindow_Loaded` to `Loaded` event of your window.
Don't forget to add a reference `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

Comment: Yes, but one error. The type or namespace name 'SHDocVw' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls`.

Comment: Great. Finally. That works for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in the code snippet what is `this.wb` and `wpfWebBrowser1`? Are they the same instance of a WPF WebControl?

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia Yes, it's my mistake when renaming here. Thanks for putting a comment about it.